# Adjectives to describe the word "questions"

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives, word-usage

I'm writing an ad for yoghurt. It's about telling the truth about the consumer's new favourite flavour. I would like to say,

> You'll need to answer some ***_*____** questions.

They're personal questions that will be asked so I was in the region of *saucy* or *juicy* but that's just not sounding right. As you can hear I'm trying to tie the adjective back to the subject of yoghurt.

Comment: Not quite sure what you're going for here. I think we need some more information about types of questions you intend on asking.  But in the mean time I'll suggest, *You'll need to answer some **cultural** questions.* ;-)

Comment: Just more provocative Jim. Saucy questions, juicy questions, spicy questions, scandalous questions.

Comment: Yoghurt really doesn't have the connotations you're looking for, Warren.  *Sharp*? *Tart*?  Best I can do, but they're not obviously yoghurty words.  I think your ad is going to fall flat unless you change your approach.

Comment: I disagree Bruce. I went with _tongue-taunting questions_ and the ad worked out nicely.

Comment: @WarrenvanRooyen What does *tongue-taunting* mean in that phrase? To *taunt* is to *challenge* or *provoke with insulting remarks*. A hot sauce might be considered *tongue-taunting* (. . .maybe), but yoghurt? It sounds like a mean, sarcastic yoghurt. I just don't see the connection. *Tongue-tempting* seems a bit more "in character", but if I saw the ad somewhere in its proposed form I would be confused and walk away.

Comment: @Zairja. It's context-dependent. The questions are of a personal nature that could land the individual in hot water. This means that the questions are taunting their tongue to answer questions that could land them in hot water; though their tongue's will wag regardless as it's a competition.

Answer (score 1):

*[Piquant](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/piquant#Adjective)* (“Engaging; charming” or “Favorably stimulating to the palate; pleasantly spicy; stimulating”) is a possibility.  For slightly blander words, consider  *[delicious](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/delicious#Adjective)* (“Pleasing to taste; tasty” or “
(colloquial) Metaphorically pleasing to taste; pleasing to the eyes or mind”) and  *[delectable](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/delectable#Adjective)* (“Pleasing to the taste; delicious”; from Medieval Latin *delectare* (“to delight”)).

Comment: Piquant is the only one there that even comes close to what Warren is asking.  He wants an implication that is personal/naughty while also dairy-product related.  Pretty much impossible, I'd say, but you should at least try for the first requirement (naughty).

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps a construction with a noun instead of an adjective

> I would like to ask some questions about your *desires*.
>   I would like to ask you about your *appetites*.
>   I would like to ask you about your *delights*.
>   or
>   I would like to ask some questions about your *passions*. (Are you *passionate* about dairy products?)
>   or perhaps
>   I would like to as some questions about your *indulgences*.